# Is "This is what I had been doing all the time before I ended doing it" correct?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

*"This is what I had been doing all the time before I ended doing it."*

I would be glad for explanation.

Comment: Perhaps you mean "That is what I had been doing all the time until I stopped doing it"

Comment: Welcome! 1) There's an "English Language Learners" stack exchange where this would be a good fit; I've voted to move it there. 2) Both there and here, we ask that you say a bit more about *what* concerns you (pure proofreading, "is there anything wrong here"-type questions, don't work well). I suspect you're asking about the use of "ended," but I don't want to assume.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking for proofreading are off-topic on ELL SE. However, questions about specific aspects of English are on-topic. So please edit your question (using the small "Edit" button under the question) to explain what aspect of the sentence you're unsure about, and what you've done to try and find an answer on your own. I won't close this question now since it wold just get bounced back to EL&U, but I recommend improving it before it gets voted closed by other users